# No function outputs being displayed in Rstudio

Tags: r, head

Help! I've got some code I've been running over the past few weeks with no issues on the latest version of R, but suddenly, I'm getting no outputs displayed for simple functions such as `head()` and `summary()`. The only change to my system has been that I've installed (and subsequently uninstalled) RStudio.

Here is the first part of my code, which has a couple of the problematic lines:

```
setwd("C://StatsData")
raw_data_file<-read.csv("train_V2.csv",head=TRUE)
#rstudioapi::writeRStudioPreference("console_max_lines", 10000)
#WRITE OUTPUT TO FILE
sink('analysis-output.txt')
#remove any null/blank values - only one entry affected (4446966 original, 4446965 remain) - uses complete.cases function
full_data_file<-raw_data_file[complete.cases(raw_data_file),]
str(full_data_file)
head(full_data_file)
```

And here is a sample of the data:

[image: Data]

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `sink` is to (quoting the help page) "divert R output to a connection". So I'm sure your `str()` and `head()` outputs are ending up in `'C://StatsData/analysis-output.txt'` rather than your console. If you don't want that to happen, don't use `sink()`.

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping that sink() would just replicate the output in the R environment, and that I'd get the results in both - I'll check the output file :)

Comment: That might work if you set `split = TRUE`... not sure, just guessing based on the description at `?sink`.

Comment: Though I'd really recommend rmarkdown in RStudio for this - the learning curve for basic competency in rmarkdown isn't too bad.

Comment: I'm having problems with wroking out how to export to pdf using rmarkdown - I'm assuming that you have to create the rmarkdown file first, then convert to pdf?

Comment: It's all handled for you. In RStudio, when you do `file > New File > R Markdown` you can select your output - HTML, PDF, or Word. This pre-fills the YAML configuration at the top with `output: pdf_document`. (Or you can edit the YAML directly.) You will need a LaTeX installation, but I'm pretty sure that comes bundled with RStudio these days.